# Is there a way to run a command on a different git branch?

Tags: git

I have a large rails project with several feature branches active at any one time.  We have a long running task (rebuild the db, run the tests).

I would like to be able to run the test task on one feature branch while changing code on another.  Is there a way to run a particular command on a certain branch, but have another branch active in another terminal?

Comment: Wouldn't two terminals both on separate branches solve the problem?

Comment: Git is a statemachine when it comes to local branches in a gitified folder, by `git checkout branch2` you change the state – which means all git commands will end up being applied to the `branch2` branch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Git commands can operate on any reference, it doesn't have to be the branch currently checked out into your working copy:

```
git log <branch>
git diff <branch-one> <branch-two>
```

Other Git commands only operate on the branch you currently have checked out in your working copy:

```
git reset --hard head@{1}
```

If your tests depend on there being a certain branch checked out into your working copy, then as far as I know, you can't have more than one branch checked out into your working copy, you can only have 1 working copy.

As an alternative, you could possibly just clone your local repo again to get a second working copy that way:

```
git clone <path to local repo> second-repo
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont think so...

If this behavior is really needed, and going to be used often, it might be worth it to clone your repository again in a different location.

Are you trying to run a command that will take a long time to run?

You could merge the two branches and run the command from the first branch, while still working on the stuff from the other branch, if your project allows.